# Setting mulltiple CSS3 backgrounds with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to know the proper way to set CSS3 multiple backgrounds for an element with jQuery. I want to end up with

```
content #{
  background:
    url(images/snapGrid2.gif) left top,
    url(clientImages/vector-old-paper-1627.jpg);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Umm... same way as you'd set literally any other CSS property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is.

```
$('.mbg').css('background', 'url(http://placehold.it/300x200) left top no-repeat, url(http://placehold.it/300x200) right bottom no-repeat')
```

Yep, it is basically the same as setting a single background image.

See it for yourself: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/ZY86A/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this plug-in I found for multiple backgrounds using jQuery [here](http://www.chicowebdesign.com/blog/2010/10/21/updated-jquery-multiple-background-plug-in/)